# The Runge - Kutta method and two-body problem

Tags: numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, runge-kutta-methods

Is it possible to get an approximation of the two body problem:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
x''(t)=-\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}, & x(0)=1-\varepsilon, &x'(0)=0\\
y''(t)= -\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}, & y(0)=0,& y'(0)=\sqrt{(1+\varepsilon)(1-\varepsilon)}
\end{array}\right.$$ 
with $\varepsilon = 0.0167$ by the Runge-Kutta fourth order method?

I think that it is not possible because the Runge-Kutta method can only solve equations of first order derivative:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
y'=f(t,y)\\
y(0)=y_0
\end{array}\right.$$

Many thanks!

Comment: Let me tell you about one of math's magic words: **let** $f(t)=x^\prime(t)$ and $g(t)=y^\prime(t)$...

Comment: It is indeed possible, but there are better methods. For the two body problem the [Leapfrog method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) is simpler and usually performs better than RK (it conserves energy while Runge-Kutta does not so if you want to study several orbits then orbits have the tendency to shrink or expand with RK).

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that for the _two_-body problem, there is a known exact solution of the equations. Technically you don't need a "numerical" solution unless you have at least three bodies in the system. (On the other hand this also makes the two-body problem useful as a way to test a proposed method for solving $n$-body problems: run the numerical method on the two-body problem and compare its results to the exact solution.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with vectors.  Define
$$\mathbf{v} = \left( \begin{matrix} x & y & x' & y' \end{matrix} \right)^T$$
and set up Runge-Kutta method in the form
$$\mathbf{v}' = f(t, \mathbf{v})$$